# How can I decrease my home partition to gives 40G to my boot pattion with dual boot (win10 and Ubuntu18)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot system Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04, need to increase my boot partition, how can I give some 40 G home partition(p7) space to boot partition(p4)?  as  I tried to use GParted, while there is the grub partition between them, seems GPated is not allowing me to resize grub partition. 
the partition table is below:

- p1 -- EFI p2--Msresere P3-- Baseddata(win10) p4-boot p5--swp
  p6--grub2 p7--home

Comment: Apologies if you know this already: you'll need to be running gparted from a live disk in order to make changes to the drive. And I'm sure you know this but everything you do with gparted be super careful because it's a very powerful tool and it didn't save me from myself when I deleted the wrong things :D

Comment: 40Gb for -boot-? why?! A size of 1Gb is more than enough.

Comment: Are you sure. I mean 40GB is OVERKILL. Are you sure you are talking about boot and not root?

Comment: sorry I mean root not boot. and Thanks for all answers. for all I already

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all fast answers. and sorry for the confusion, I mean root not boot.  for all I already successfully did it by shrinking  Win10 partition
 [image]